# Jython 2.2.1, howto move a file? shutils.move is non-existant!

Tags: java, python, jython, file-handling, shutil

```
'''use Jython'''

import shutil

print dir(shutil)
```

There is no, shutil.move, how does one move a file with Jython?
and while we at it, how does one delete a file with Jython?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.rename()` to move, and `os.unlink()` to delete -- just like Python pre-`shutil`.

Comment: Note that os.rename will be different to shutil.move if the destination is on a different filesystem.  shutil falls back to a copy+delete in this situation, but rename will just fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you need support for moving across filesystems, consider just copying CPython's `shutil.py` into your project. [The Python License](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.2/license/) is flexible enough to allow this (even for commercial projects), as long as licensing and attribution information are retained.

Comment: Or copy shutil.py from Jython 2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = File(filename_old)
f1.nameTo(File(filename_new))
```